# Using different Microsoft Cognitve servers with one access key

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

FaceAPI services. Using inside ASP.NET MVC web application. Net Framework 4.6

In Apr/2017 I obtained free access key for FaceAPI, however, for some unknown for me reason i could access only "West US" server (westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com) and general server (api.cognitive.microsoft.com).

Once i am trying to login into "West Europe" server i got error "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."

So, my questions are:

1) how can I connect to "West Europe" server ?

2) where I could see to what region belong my subscription key?

Answer (score 1):

The West Europe API endpoint is `https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0`.  As you've discovered, a subscription key for one region is not valid in another.

I'm not aware of any subscription key -> location mapping.  Since the only two options available to you right now are 'westus' and 'westeuprope', you could determine which through the process of elimination.

Comment: where I could see to what region belong my subscription key?

Comment: Did you get the key via the Azure portal, or the Cognitive Services website?  As I mentioned in the answer, I'm not aware of how one determines the region (or even the API) base on the subscription key.

Comment: I do not have Azure account. I got key via Cognitive Services web site, by using my Microsoft account, which was registered many years ago. Unfortunately I do not remember in what country i was...

Comment: I believe the web site only serves keys for westus.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to change region. During registration in Microsoft\Azure you indicate your `Country`, that is it, no more way to change it.