# Never Valid Microsoft Cognitive API Keys

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Today I subscribed to the Face API with a free account here https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions. I verified my email and got 2 keys applied to my account.

In practice, these keys were both invalid. I waited a few hours to see if they would kick in but they never did.

I regenerated one of the keys and also waited a few hours and that one never was valid either.

Using https://eastus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/console
In order to test the validity of the keys.

Is there another process in order to get these keys to be actually usable?

Comment: try to use `general` server or `westus` server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590249/using-different-microsoft-cognitve-servers-with-one-access-key

Comment: This was an issue with `eastus2` vs `westus` servers. It isn't clear on their site that the API keys are server dependent. After switching to `westus` everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds exactly like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744197/401-access-denied-with-cognitive-services-keys-not-azure-account), except for `eastus2` instead of `westeurope`.